# Using a search text box on a sharepoint list >500 items

Tags: powerapps

I have a list of items 'Achievements'

That currently I am filtering to populate a gallery like this:

```
SortByColumns(Filter('Achievements',  
Email = CurrentUser.Email And Role=SKlvl And Achieved = false And SKlvl = Role),
"Priority",If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

The search box I want to search with is TextSearchBox1_1

I was previously just using `TextSearchBox1_1.Text  in Title` to perform searches and this was working well.
However as more users were added to the list it quickly grew over 500 entries and my search function had to be sacrificed to allow delegation to work.

I've spent a couple of hours trying to resolve this and cannot get around the issue.

Is there some way that I can pass the result of my Filter to something else than can then perform searching ?
Or do I just need to sacrifice the search functionality and move on with my life ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Options:

- I believe you can create a Collection with >500 records in it then reference the local Collection rather than reach out to SP. . You may try creating this using the `OnStart` property of the app itself.
- Add some kind of column to your Sharepoint list that pares records down to a number that will always be <500 records, then query that from PowerApps. (Careful here. Sharepoint calculated columns don't play nice with all PowerApps queries)
- Move your data over to Azure SQL or the PowerApps Common Data Source (CDS) to avert Delegation issues.

Comment: Went back and put it into a collection this  worked pretty well, cheers.